# file not downloading from ftp server(android)

Tags: android, ftp, download

I am not being able to download the files from the ftp server to my android device. following is my code. I am using common net 3.3 reference library for access to the ftp server. app runs without any errors but doesn't download the file.

```
package com.anis.ftpdownload;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    System.out.println("main");
    downloadFile();

}

private void downloadFile() {

    System.out.println("download file reached");

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect("islingtonproject.comxa.com", 21);
        ftpClient.login("usr","pass");
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        System.out.println("ftpclient connected");


        String remoteFile1 = "/csv/s.csv";
        File downloadFile1 = new File("/sdcard/s.csv");
        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
        boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
        outputStream1.close();

        System.out.println("downloading");

        if (!success) {
            System.out.println("File #1 download failed.");
        }

        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Of course you have errors. You will have a NetworkOnMainThreadException to begin with. Your network code should be placed in a thread or asynctask. Further remoteFile1 should only be a filename. Not a subdir and a filename. Do a change current working directory to csv first.

Comment: Can you please help me with code. I am beginner. So I  Can't understand you

Comment: Just click the ftp button for seeings questions concerning ftp. Read a lot of them and soon you will find how to code my suggestions.

Comment: I have researched lot on ftp client on android before posting this question but none of them were using asynctask class

Comment: They were. Or using a thread. But they did not post code for that as it was irrelevant for their problem. You have a NetworkOnMainThread exception. Look in the logcat.

Comment: I successfully downloaded the file using asynctask but it is empty. Any help?

Comment: I would not call that 'successfully'. Please show complete code.

Comment: Please click this link for the code.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dWsZzA-3PYMXBPX1g2SDZDblk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There was no reason posting code on google drive. Please post all code here. The implementation with an async task looks ok so now we can concentrate on the actual code. You changed `String remoteFile1 = "/csv/s.csv"; `to `String remoteFile1 = "/s.csv";`. Why? Did you try "s.csv" also? If you log in with apps like ES File Explorer or AndFtp then in which directory do you land? And using FileZilla? My experience is that different ftp clients can 'land' in different 'root' directories? Find out in which directory you land with `System.out.println ("CWD: "+ ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory() );`.

Comment: thanks. I am grateful for your help. I had completed my project in August. Sorry for thanking you so late.